# state space model

Tags: stochastic-processes

i would   like to understand basic  idea   of state space model,generally definition of state space model says that

State space model (SSM) refers to a class of probabilistic graphical model (Koller and Friedman, 2009) that describes the probabilistic dependence between the latent state variable and the observed measurement. The state or the measurement can be either continuous or discrete

now consider following situation,suppose  our model is consisted by stat equation and observation equation,where state equation is  given by following formula

$X(t+1)=A*x(t)+n(t)$

where A is an n × n state-transition matrix,so it means that it describes  transition places for given   position?and $n(t)$ is Gaussian noise,and also observation equation is described by:
The m-dimensional measurement y(t) is subject to a linear transformation of the hidden state x(t) and is further corrupted by a measurement noise process v(t)

$y(t)=B*x(t)+v(t)$

now i am confused in the following  things,first equation  simply says that  state equation represents  similar to random walk,we have transition matrix  as given in the following link(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix), but what  does second equation shows?
what is a measurement in this case?i am interested  meaning of measurement in such models,
i have started  learning state space models  a few days ago and i am still confused in several terminology,firs  such terminology is measurement    definition,thanks a lot

Comment: First, in many applications, the $A$ matrix is not a transition matrix in the sense of giving probabilities of moving to a new state, rather, it is an autoregression vector.  That is, it tells you how $x$ depends on past values of itself.  Thus, in an economic context, output today might depend on past output and past consumption.  $B$ can be similar: observed output (or rocket position etc.) can depend on some linear combination of actual output plus noise.

Comment: thanks for replay @Trurl,for  make it more clear for me,A matrix  tell us  how  x depend on it's pas value,but observed  output in this case what does represent?let say airplane  position at given time is depend  on it's position at previous time +noise right?but what about observed position what does it shows? it is also called measurement also yes?

Comment: @Amzoti  i have updated it,sorry

Comment: On the air traffic controller's radar screen, the observed position is the actual position plus noise (roughly) but you can imagine that the radar bounce depends on other factors in $x$ such as speed, altitude, even past position (because of slight lags in the radar equipment).  Or, in the context I know better, you only have an estimate of the actual unemployment rate, not the true rate, and perhaps with  unemployment being high for a while, people are embarrased to admit that, so your measurement error depends on lagged values as well. Hope this helps.

Comment: so it means that  position and  observation is almost  same,just in case of observation  we are  involving  some additional parameters   to  actual position?so it means that if   we have estimated  airplane position from previous time,then for estimate observation we should consider  other factors for get true position?does it means that we are not trusting actual position  estimation only  by noise and    previous position?

Comment: or take this example,let us  consider  airplane position  fixed by  radar control system,we know it's position at  time let say $t=10$,for  get  position at time $t=11$,we need first to add  previous  position multiplied  by some auto-regressive vector and + noise right? we get position,but now  i want to estimate  observation,this observation what  does show me  ?just it is same as  previous position,but considered several other factor,like wind speed,acceleration.velocities and so on?

Comment: Basically, your fist equation is your system **model**, i.e. how you expect your system to move on to step 11 given step 10. $n(t)$ denotes the *modeling error*, e.g. errors due to numerical calculations.$$$$

The second equation describes your system **observation** i.e. the output of your sensors and can be anything from velocity to torque or position. The error term $v(t)$ denotes the *measurement error* which stems from non ideal sensors.

Comment: now it became clear for me i think,it is  like how i expect my  system move from one position to another,while observation is how does  it really move right?

Comment: Well, the way I've usually interpreted it is that $x(t)$ describes the actual position of the system, the truth, and the $x(t+1)$ equation describes how the position changes.  The airplane's change of position depends on speed, direction, and so forth, but also random things like gusts of wine (the $n(t)$).  But you don't know the truth, you only have an imperfect observation--and how that observation-what you see--depends on the truth, is what the $y(t)$ equation tells you.

Comment: i see now,thank a lot of